# Which data do I need to calculate the probability of a person dying of certain disease when I know the deaths per 100.000 inhabitants?

Tags: probability

*This is a extremely unpleasant topic to talk or read about, so I apologize if it makes you uncomfortable reading it (and may be you want to skip it and not continue reading after reading this, if you are too sensitive about talking about diseases and probability of deaths resulting of them, so here it's your warning), but it's a mathematical problem that's presented in my real life and I don't know how to solve it.*

Half of my relatives have gotten cancer in the last 20 years at the ages of 40-50-60 years. This is devastating and makes you consider life choice decisions. According to some statistics from my area, mortality of cancer is 151.14 per 100,000 inhabitants . This is more or less 1 in 662 persons die of cancer each year where I live. I've had statistics and other 10 mathematics curses in the universities I attended, but it was many years ago and honestly I don't know how to face this mathematical problem.

I want to convert the mortality rate of cancer, plus some additional data I can gather (such as life expectancy, may be) into the probability of a person from my generation dying of cancer in his lifetime, if it's possible. What I want to know is if my relatives (blood unrelated many times) are extremely unlucky or it's mathematically probable for a person of my generation to have around 50% of chances of dying of cancer like it happened to my relatives. One attempt to solve the problem, I thought it could be multiplying the probability by year by the life expectancy for the people of my area after getting this figure, but I don't know if it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with science of [Actuarial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_science). It is an entire field of statistics in itself.